# What is Join() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is Join() in jquery? for example:

```
var newText = $("p").text().split(" ").join("</span> <span>");
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

That's not a jQuery function - it's the regular [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function.

It converts an array to a string, putting the argument between each element.

Answer (score 19):

You would probably use your example like this

```
var newText = "<span>" + $("p").text().split(" ").join("</span> <span>") + "</span>";
```

This will put span tags around all the words in you paragraphs, turning

```
<p>Test is a demo.</p>
```

into

```
<p><span>Test</span> <span>is</span> <span>a</span> <span>demo.</span></p>
```

I do not know what the practical use of this could be.

Comment: you could fade in each word... or apply other effects.

Answer (score 10):

The practical use of this construct? It is a javascript replaceAll() on strings.

```
var s = 'stackoverflow_is_cool';  
s = s.split('_').join(' ');  
console.log(s);
```

will output:

```
stackoverflow is cool
```

Comment: but that would be just so much easier like this `'stackoverflow_is_cool'.replace(/_/g," ")`

Answer (score 5):

join is not a jQuery function .Its a javascript function.

The join() method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.The elements will be separated by a specified separator. The default separator is comma (,).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 2):

I use join to separate the word in array with `"and, or , / , &"`

**EXAMPLE**

**HTML**

```
<p>London Mexico Canada</p>
<div></div>
```

**JS**

```
 newText = $("p").text().split(" ").join(" or ");
 $('div').text(newText);
```

**Results**

```
London or Mexico or Canada
```

Answer (score 1):

A practical example using a jQuery example might be

```
 var today = new Date();
 $('#'+[today.getMonth()+1, today.getDate(), today.getFullYear()].join("_")).whatever();
```

I do that in a calendar tool that I am using, this way on the page load, I can do certain things with today's date.