# Delimiting a text string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

I am collecting the text from several elements like this:-

```
$('#element').find('p').text();
```

However this returns the text of all the 'p' elements added together without any form of delimiting.  e.g. If each 'p' element contains a musician/artist name I get the following when collecting them all:-

The BeatlesRadioheadBritney Spears

What I want to do is insert a space (or comma) between each artist so that the above list looks like:-

The Beatles Radiohead Britney Spears

I would imagine the .map/.split/.join function will do the trick but my inexperience with jQuery is holding me back here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you could use join. This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593770/what-is-join-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about using `.map` along with `.join`.

Try something like this:

```
var names = $('#element').find('p').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');
console.log(names); //The Beatles,Radiohead,Britney Spears
```

Comment: Perfect!  Many thanks, it works beautifully. I was definitely along the right lines, but as I said my inexperience with the syntax left me confusing myself.