# Create One String from All element use Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delimiting a text string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890928/delimiting-a-text-string-with-jquery)

i have create one string from all `.postTag` use jquery

```
sample:
    <span class='postTag'>Jquery</span>
    <span class='postTag'>php</span>
    <span class='postTag'>mysql</span>
```

**output :**

```
<input type='hidden' id='allInsertedTags' value='Jquery,php,mysql' />
```

*thank You ;D*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("span.postTag").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = $('.postTag').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(', ');​
$('#allInsertedTags').val(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/qwtJx/)

```
strings = []
$.each($(".postTag"), function(k,v) {
   strings.push($(this).text())            
})
join = strings.join(",")
$("<input>").attr({
type: "hidden",
id: "allInsertedTags",
value: join
}).appendTo("body")
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function from jQuery.