# Trying to create a comma delimited string

Tags: jquery

I was trying to follow this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890928/delimiting-a-text-string-with-jquery)

```
var tags = $('#MainContent_myTable tr').each(function () {
return $(this).find('.tablecellname').html();
}).get().join(',');
console.log(tags);
```

When I look at the output I get the following:

```
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],  
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement], 
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],  
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement], 
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement], 
[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement],...
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Is that from `IE console`?

Comment: `.text()` instead of `.html()`?

Comment: is there any particular reason you're not including the `.tablecellname` portion in the outer selector?

Comment: @Alnitak - nice!  Not my code.  just tested it. made it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
var tags = $('#MainContent_myTable tr').map(function () {
    return $(this).find('.tablecellname').html();
}).get().join(',');
console.log(tags);
```