# Getting Columns Checked in GridView with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView and am needing to grab column 1 and 2 (the text therein) and put that text elsewhere in the page, another textbox.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
 var checked = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
            //place airport in textbox, txtAirport
            var loc = $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(1)");
            var ac = $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(2)");

            // txtAirport.Text = loc + ac;
            $("#<%= txtAirport.ClientID%>").val(loc + ac);
        });
```

the problem is I am getting {Object object} {Object object} in my textbox where I'm expecting to get a city, st and an airport. How do I clarify my "loc" and "ac" variables to give me what I need? I've tried .text and .val() to no avail.

Here is the HTML (ASP.NET Gridview):

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="dgSearch" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="False"
                            CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" ShowFooter="False" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <AlternatingItemStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="HeaderRowAlternate"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Wrap="False" CssClass="HeaderRowStyle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Select">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HEADERSTYLE"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLookup" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox"></asp:CheckBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="AirportID"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn Visible="False" DataField="City"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Loc" HeaderText="Location">
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="HEADERSTYLE"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="AirportCode" HeaderText="Airport Code">
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="HEADERSTYLE"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="AirportName" HeaderText="Airport Name">
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="HEADERSTYLE"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:BoundColumn>
                                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MilesFromSource" HeaderText="Distance">
                                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" CssClass="HEADERSTYLE"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                                </asp:BoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors return wrapped sets containing the selected DOM elements, so you'll need to use .text() or .html()

EDIT: OK, I've replicated your code, what you need is

```
$("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(2)");
$("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(3)");
```

And then to do

```
$("#<%= txtAirport.ClientID%>").val(loc[0].innerHTML + ac[0].innerHTML);
```

This will give you the text in the first and second columns (after the checkbox) of the first row (loc[1] and ac[1] for second rows etc.). The issue you had was `td:nth-child(0)` was returning the DOM object of the checkbox's `<td>` element

To loop through checked checkboxes only:

```
for (var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
    alert(loc[i].innerHTML + " " + ac[i].innerHTML);
}
```

You don't need to check the checkbox is checked since the jQuery selector already does that for you

Comment: .html() gives me a ton of html, far too much actually. It's like my variables are not explicit enough.

Comment: for some reason I keep getting the correct column headers just not the column data.

Comment: I changed it to loc[1].innerHTML and ac[1].innerHTML and am getting back the first row that was checked. Now I need to add to my textbox the other values that were checked.

Comment: Updated with how to loop through checked rows

Comment: for some reason when I loop through here it places the last item in the GridView (not the checked boxes). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by last item and what's being place where? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery returns an array or matched objects so you need to use `loc[0].innerHTML` or `loc.html()` or `loc.text()` instead of `loc` (or `ac` respectively).

```
   var checked = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
        //place airport in textbox, txtAirport
        var loc = $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(2)");
        var ac = $("tr:has(:checkbox:checked) td:nth-child(3)");

        // txtAirport.Text = loc + ac;
        $("#<%= txtAirport.ClientID%>").val(loc.html() + ac.html());
    });
```

It is probably necessary to change numbers of cells too (1,2 -> 2,3) see http://jsfiddle.net/vXtKq/
It can be that you selector is not specific enough but if you post result of upper code or **rendered** HTML (from page source in your browser) the finding of solution is easier.

Comment: I'm using "loc" only as a variable here. Can you clarify?

Comment: As I understand it loc should contain what jQuery matched (var loc = $...) but it is not a text in <td> it is jQuery object - generaly array of HTML objects. To get content of first loc.html() is used.

Comment: by changing it to that I get the desired column headers but not the content of the columns of the rows that were clicked.

Comment: It is necessary to change the numbers too see updated answer and example.

Comment: I think I've got it but I need to be able to grab all of the items that were checked, not just the one. to do that I have to iterate thru this somehow?

Comment: You can try join http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593770/what-is-join-in-jquery, but I think that you need to iterate for (var i=0;i<loc.length;i++)res=res+loc[i]+ac[i];