# Issue with dynamic table generation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, dynamic-tables

I have tried generating dynamic tables in Jquery using join method. Here is my HTML code

```
<table id="mark" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="width: 100%;font-family: Georgia;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>rollno</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is Jquery part

```
var r = new Array();
var j = -1, recordId;          
for (var key=0; key<data.length; key++){
    var obj = data[key];
    r[++j] =  makeRow(obj);  
}
$('#mark tbody').html(r.join(''));
function makerow(row){
    row = $('<tr><td>'+row.name+'</td><td>'+row.rollno+'</td></tr>');
    return row;
}
```

As a result I am  not getting anything. But when I tried printing data in console, it has good values. Here is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/yLSy9/9/ . I have hard coded some values instead of data

Comment: `join()` is for concatenating strings. The elements of `r` are jQuery objects, not strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Join() in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593770/what-is-join-in-jquery)

Comment: @Barmar , see this link, its possible to do with join .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864294/dynamic-creation-of-large-html-table-in-javascript-performance

Comment: In that question they join the strings of HTML, not the jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use append instead of join.Also you have called function with wrong name. you have called it by make**R**ow() and it is make**r**ow()

```js
function makerow(){
    row = $('<tr><td>John</td><td>12324</td></tr>');

    return row;
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
var r = new Array();
              var j = -1, recordId;          
               for (var key=0; key<5; key++){
                   //var obj = data[key];
                   r[++j] =  makerow();  
               }
               $('#mark tbody').append(r);
               
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mark" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="width: 100%;font-family: Georgia;">
                                     <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                            <th>name</th>
                                            <th>rollno</th>

                                        </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                      </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: worked well. Can we do something to improve performance ? . Its taking time to populate if we have huge data

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` works with an array of strings, not jQuery objects. Change `makerow()` so that it returns a string rather than wrapping it with `$()`.

```
function makerow(row){
    row = '<tr><td>'+row.name+'</td><td>'+row.rollno+'</td></tr>';
    return row;
}
```